# PostgreSQL Full Text Search Accuracy

Tags: django, postgresql

Is there any way to improve the accuracy of Full Text Search on Postgres? I'm using it with Django and a simple search for `invest` doesn't return results with the word `investor`. I assume this is because the stemming algorithm is returning invest* and investor as two different stems.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    query_string = self.request.GET.get('q')
    vector = SearchVector('description', weight='A') + SearchVector('location', weight='A') + SearchVector('name', weight='A')
    query = SearchQuery(query_string)
    return PeopleSnapshot.objects.annotate(rank=SearchRank(vector, query)).order_by('-rank')
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a query you are running that is not working?

Comment: @IainShelvington the `invest` not returning `investor` is one example. I think a solution might be to change out the Stemmer from Snowball maybe to Lancaster, but I'm not sure if that's possible.

Comment: Just share an example and we might be able to help?

Comment: @IainShelvington I added an example, but it's how I'm calling it in Django– I'm not writing a raw search query so I'm not sure if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

For your particular example a ["synonym dictionary"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-SYNONYM-DICTIONARYSIMPLE-DICTIONARY) should help.

There are also more sophisticated "thesaurus dictionaries" and you can customise the actual stemming by changing the "ispell dictionary". Both mentioned on that same page.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using the `english` text search configuration.

`investor` is *not* reduced to `invest` by the stemming algorithm:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('english', 'investor');

 to_tsvector  
--------------
 'investor':1
(1 row)
```

If you want a prefix match, you'll have to do it like this:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('english', 'investor')
       @@ to_tsquery('english', 'invest:*');

 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```